# In Wpf, How to wait for all desendents to finish cleanup?

Tags: .net, wpf, windows

I am using wpf. I want to:

- Close a window
- Wait for all desendents finish cleanup
- Then run some other code

Currently, I use the `Unloaded` event to cleanup some unmanaged resources. 
However, Based on observation and documentation, the `Unloaded` event is fired top to bottom:

- Window `Unloaded`
- Children `Unloaded`
- Grandchildren `Unloaded`
- ...

Which dose not allow me to do what I want.

And `Window.Closed` is even fired before `Unloaded`.

Is there any built-in solution for this problem?

Or do I have to roll my own?

e.g. implement IDisposable for all of my controls. Like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23200671/5381855).